# count() takes lots of time when use WHERE clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table has approximately 100 000 records(tuples). Without where clause it takes only few miliseconds whereas takes 4-5 secs when use where clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM tablename WHERE shippable = '1'
```

I also tried this one but it takes more time as compared to previous one.

```
SELECT count(rowsss) FROM (SELECT count(*) as rowsss FROM tablename WHERE shippable = '1' GROUP BY id) as T
```

This is the output when I use EXPLAIN keyword before starting of mysql query

[image]

Comment: you might need an index on the "shippable" column

Comment: Do you have duplicate ids in your table? Surely your id should be a unique identifier for each record! If they are unique, then using DISTINCT is an unnecessary overhead

Comment: This is not an indexing problem.I have tried with indexing but there is no luck.

Comment: Yes, I have duplicate ids in the table.This ids is not used as a primary key.

Comment: Try sticking `EXPLAIN` on the start of your query - see what the database server has to actually say about it, it'll help you figure out what needs optimising.

Comment: I tried EXPLAIN before query.I am not understanding the output.I am adding my **explain query** output in question.Please help me.

Comment: If it is a common query, consider partitioning by shippable column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you a need  a filter you could use an index on shippable eg:

```
 create index shippable_ixd on tablename (shippable);
```

in this way the scan for the table is limited to values that match 
and avoid the scan for entire table

and based on the fact you also need  the column `id` you could also trying alternatively a composite index

```
 create index shippable_ixd on tablename (shippable, id);
```

the sqloptimizer should retrive directly form the index the info needed.

In this case The use of composite index ( with a redundant id not need by where clause)   is useful because the SQL engine retrive all the data needed  to the query just scanning the index, avoiding the access  to the data in the table. This tecnique is use frequently for db queries tuning.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am trying this one but there is no benefit.I think this problem is related to **count()**.

Comment: I have update the answer  with  suggestion for a composite index

Comment: answer update with some explanations .. hope is useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163181/discussion-between-sumit-and-scaisedge).

Comment: @Sumit  you need others explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

When you checking any condition that time both value should be in same type then execution of query will be fast.

```
SELECT count(rowsss) FROM (SELECT count(*) as rowsss FROM tablename WHERE CAST(shippable  AS CHAR) = '1' GROUP BY id) as T
```